# render a partial form using the javascript variable in views rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is the code to get the selected drop down value...

```
var rolename = $("#server_role_ids").find(':selected').text();
```

This is the code calling the partial form from the JS by writing it statically the name of the form. In this case "web"

```
$('#role_form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "web") %>');
```

but I want to dynamically call the partial form using the rolename variable, like the below to get that particular selected form:

```
$('#role_form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "" + rolename) %>');
```

if the `rolename` is "something" call that "something" partial form.

I know this stuff like `if (rolename == "web")` do this `else if (rolename == "relay")`, do that. But I want it dynamically so that I could write it without any if else statements.

Need help guys.

The things I tried with AJAX

I tried with implementing with AJAX, I don't know whether it is the right way to do it. Please let me know. 
This is new.html.erb javascript...

```
$.ajax({ url : "/servers/new", type : "post", data : {RoleName : rolename , envId : environmentid}, dataType: "text" });
```

So I have sent the variable to the controller

```
@rolename = params[:RoleName]
```

And want to use it like this..

```
$('#role_form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "#{@rolename}") %>');
```

in the views, new.html.erb.

Is it the right way of doing it with AJAX? What can I do it to make it work? or any other idea or suggestion from you??

Comment: The server code (erb) is executed first and then the client code (JS), so the JS is not available when needed in your scenario.  You could implement this with AJAX but that may be overkill.

Comment: I tried with implementing with AJAX, I don't know whether it is the right way to do it. Please let me know.

This is new.html.erb javascript...
 $.ajax({
         url : "/servers/new",
         type : "post",
         data : {RoleName : rolename , envId : environmentid},
         dataType: "text"
        });
So I have sent the variable to the controller 

@rolename = params[:RoleName]

And want to use it like this..

$('#role_form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "#{@rolename}") %>'); in the views, new.html.erb
Is it the right way ? Can I do it to make it work? or any other ?

Comment: please edit your OP to add code.  It is very hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: I updated the question, please review it..